# About "Load" event

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, events

I know that in C# the Form.Load event occurs only before the form is displayed for the first time.
Is there any similar event handler (in C#) which occurs every time that the form is displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're showing and hiding the form instead of destroying it.. then you can hook into the [VisibleChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and perform some code when its `Visible` property is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be

- **`Shown`** event - fired when the form is first shown
- **`Load`** event - fired whenever the user loads the form
- `Activate` event - fired each time the form is activated or receives the focus
- `VisibleChanged` event - fired whenever the visibility changes